# Mysql client within ssh within expect quoting annoyance

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, expect

I'm trying to execute the following in a bash script:

```
REPLICATION_USER_SETUP=$(expect -c "spawn ssh $LDAP_USER@$MASTER_IP_ADDRESS \"mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --socket=$MYSQL_SOCKET --execute \"GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO \'$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER\'@\'$SLAVE_IP_ADDRESS\' IDENTIFIED BY \'$MYSQL_REPLICATION_PW\';\"\";expect Password:;send $LDAP_PASS\r;interact")
```

But I keep getting "extra characters after close-quote" whenever I try to run it.
I've tried variations of double and single escaped quotes, but nothing seems to be working.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

try escaping backslashes of sql query:

```
REPLICATION_USER_SETUP=$(expect -c "spawn ssh $LDAP_USER@$MASTER_IP_ADDRESS \"mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --socket=$MYSQL_SOCKET --execute \\\"GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO \'$MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER\'@\'$SLAVE_IP_ADDRESS\' IDENTIFIED BY \'$MYSQL_REPLICATION_PW\';\\\"\";expect Password:;send $LDAP_PASS\r;interact")
```